# Booting CentOS from live usb on OSX El Capitan

Tags: linux, centos, osx, live-usb

I have been trying to set up a live usb to use to study for the RHCSA/RHCE certification. CentOS launches and gives me the launch page I choose the standard option, I have not tried text mode etc. From here it tries to start the OS. All I get is an error. 
[image: Error Message]

How can I get a live usb Centos working on my Mac book pro?

Answer (score 0):

Do this in VirtualBox.  Just set the Live CD iso as your boot device and boot your machine.  You should have no problems.